# Function call into other function with js object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I have two functions one and two, where function one calls in second function but it doesn't work,

for example:

```
function one() {
 var a = 1;
 var position = {
  global: function(b) {
    console.log(b);
  }
 }
}

function two(){
 $(window).on('swipedown', function() {
   one();
   position.global(a);
});
}

two();
```

demo`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezqwt6rq/)

Comment: You need to declare both `a` and `position` in a shared scope

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ca9sz05w/1/

Comment: Other way would be to make your function returning relevant variables if you don't want to pollute the outer scope

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the a and position object outside the function to avoid closure.

```
var a = null, position = {};

function one() {
  a = 1;
  position = {
  global: function(b) {
    console.log(b);
  }
 }
}

function two(){
 $(window).on('swipedown', function() {
   one();
   position.global(a);
});
}

two();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the scope of the variables `a` and `position`, since you have declared them in the function `one`, it exists only inside that function, once the function is exited the variables are no longer available.

Since you are accessing the variables in function `two`, you need to declare them in a shared scope like

```js
var position, a;

function one() {
  a = 1;
  position = {
    global: function(b) {
      snippet.log('b:' + b);
    }
  }
}

function two() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    one();
    position.global(a);
  });
}

two();
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Another way to use the variable `a` is to make use of closure like

```js
var position;

function one() {
  var a = 1;
  position = {
    global: function() {
      snippet.log('a:' + a);
    }
  }
}

function two() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    one();
    position.global();
  });
}

two();
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```